# Creating a slidshow in android

Tags: java, android, imageview

I am creating an application in which user can start slideshow (auto-play) of images by clicking a specific button. I have started a thread in which a new image is set to my imageView after a 1 sec. Problem is that my app stop responding and crashes after few seconds.

Please check my code and help me to resolve this issue. (variables are correctly initialized)

```
 playThread = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (this) {
            for (int i=pos;i<mImageIds.length;i++){
            //pos++;

            selectedImage.setImageResource(mImageIds[i]);

            try {

                wait(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }}
        }};

    play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            runOnUiThread(playThread);



        }   
    });

}
```

my logcat while app freezes!

[image]

Comment: Do you have any *errors* in your LogCat...?

Comment: no....same message every time (GC_ALLOC....see the logcat snap).

Comment: You can filter the level of logcat errors in eclipse. @Embattled Swag is looking for errors. You say you got crashes, so you got logs. We all need them, otherwise, we're blind. Garbage collection logs are not so important during android development (in some situations much more advanced let's say).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The runOnUiThread() method is meant to update the user interface. Any other logic shouldn't happen there. So I would suggest something like this:

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
    for (int i=pos;i<mImageIds.length;i++){
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                selectedImage.setImageResource(mImageIds[i]);
        }};);
    try {
        wait(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}};

play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        t.start();
    }   
});
```

Please note, I didn't test this code.